# mysql order by with limit

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a query where I want to get the 20 most popular locations from a table, and then order them alphabetically.  I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or more efficient way to do this?

```
SELECT
  city
FROM (
  SELECT 
    city, 
    count(*) AS cnt
  FROM locations 
  GROUP BY city
  ORDER BY cnt DESC
  LIMIT 20
) s ORDER BY city;
```

Comment: Maybe because I wasn't sure if it was the most efficient way, so I wanted to ask??

Comment: @Lion Actually, he's retrieving an unused field. Not much of an improvement anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly cleaner:

```
SELECT city FROM (
  SELECT city FROM locations 
  GROUP BY city
  ORDER BY count(*) DESC
  LIMIT 20
) s ORDER BY city
```

You don't need to retrieve the `count(*)` if you're not going to use it.